# Replacing parts of a complicated expression with shorthand symbols

Tags: replacement, searching

I have a list, each element of which contains a different complicated expression. Here is a simplified example of the first three entries of the list, displayed one above the other:

$\frac{Ey \ \mu \ e^{t_1-t_2}}{\hbar}+\frac{Ex \ \mu \ e^{t_1-t_6}}{\hbar}$

$-e^{t_2-t_9}(a+b+c)+\frac{Ex \ \mu \ e^{t_2-t_{24}}}{\hbar}$

$\frac{e^{t_3-t_{17}}}{\hbar}+\frac{Ey \ \mu \ e^{t_3-t_{24}}}{\hbar}$

I would like to replace certain parts of each expression with a shorthand notation. I have put in a matrix (let's call it matrix1) the bits of the expressions which I want to replace, where a particular row of the matrix contains sub-expressions from the expression which appears in the same row number in the list, and the column number corresponds to the subscript of *t* in the sub-expression that I want to replace. For example, the sub-expression $\frac{\mu \ e^{t_2-t_{24}}}{\hbar}$ is situated in row 2 (because we have $t_2$), column 24 (because we have $-t_{24}$. All of the sub-expressions to be substituted with shorthands conform to this pattern).

The shorthand notation is contained in another matrix (let it be called matrix2) which is organised so that there is a one-to-one correspondence between this and matrix1 - i.e. such that the sub-expression in element *(i,j)* of matrix1 should be replaced in the list with the contents of element *(i,j)* of matrix2.

Here is a simplified example of what I mean:
The first entry of the list is $\frac{Ey \ \mu \ e^{t_1-t_2}}{\hbar}+\frac{Ex \ \mu \ e^{t_1-t_6}}{\hbar}$. I would like to replace $\frac{\mu \ e^{t_1-t_2}}{\hbar}$ in the first term with $Cp_{1,2}$ (I choose the subscripts *1,2* for the following reason: 1 because it's the first expression in the list and 2 because there is $-t_2$ contained in the term to be replaced). Similarly, I would like to replace $\frac{\mu \ e^{t_1-t_6}}{\hbar}$ in the second term with $Cp_{1,6}$.

**My question is, how do I automate this process so that all sub-expressions in matrix1 are replaced in the list with the shorthands in one go?** All I want to do is essentially search and replace in the list by matching sub-expressions from matrix1 within the list and replacing them with the corresponding terms in matrix2.

Here is the code for the actual first expression in the list:

```
(E^(time/Subscript[t, 1] - time/Subscript[t, 9]) Ey \[Micro] Uparam[time][9])/(2 \[HBar]) +
(-E^(time/Subscript[t, 1] - time/Subscript[t, 16]) Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], hh] -
E^(time/Subscript[t, 1] - time/Subscript[t, 16]) Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], sp] + 
E^(time/Subscript[t, 1] - time/Subscript[t, 16]) Subscript[\[Omega], 0]) Uparam[time][16] -
(E^(time/Subscript[t, 1] - time/Subscript[t, 24]) Ex \[Micro] Uparam[time][24])/(2 \[HBar])
```

The first row of matrix1 contains all of the sub-expressions I wish to replace in element one of the list, so here is the first row of matrix1:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (E^(time (1/Subscript[t, 1] - 1/Subscript[t, 9])) \[Micro])/(
2 \[HBar]), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(time (1/Subscript[t, 1] - 1/Subscript[t, 16])) 
(Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], hh] + Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], sp] - Subscript[\[Omega], 
0]), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -((E^(time (1/Subscript[t, 1] - 1/Subscript[t, 24]))
\[Micro])/(2 \[HBar])), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Note that matrix1 is sparse.

And here is row 1 of matrix2:

```
{Subscript[Cp, 1, 1], Subscript[Cp, 1, 2], Subscript[Cp, 1, 3], Subscript[Cp, 1, 4], 
Subscript[Cp, 1, 5], Subscript[Cp, 1, 6], Subscript[Cp, 1, 7], Subscript[Cp, 1, 8],
Subscript[Cp, 1, 9], Subscript[Cp, 1, 10], Subscript[Cp, 1, 11], Subscript[Cp, 1, 12],
Subscript[Cp, 1, 13], Subscript[Cp, 1, 14], Subscript[Cp, 1, 15], Subscript[Cp, 1, 16],
Subscript[Cp, 1, 17], Subscript[Cp, 1, 18], Subscript[Cp, 1, 19], Subscript[Cp, 1, 20],
Subscript[Cp, 1, 21], Subscript[Cp, 1, 22], Subscript[Cp, 1, 23], Subscript[Cp, 1, 24],
Subscript[Cp, 1, 25], Subscript[Cp, 1, 26], Subscript[Cp, 1, 27], Subscript[Cp, 1, 28],
Subscript[Cp, 1, 29], Subscript[Cp, 1, 30], Subscript[Cp, 1, 31], Subscript[Cp, 1, 32],
Subscript[Cp, 1, 33], Subscript[Cp, 1, 34], Subscript[Cp, 1, 35]}
```

I expected that this simple code:

```
For[j = 1, j < 36,
Vector[[1]] = ExpandAll[Simplify[Vector[[1]], matrix1[[1]][[j]] == matrix2[[1]][[j]]]];
j++]
```

would do the right thing. However, surprisingly, the substitution only works when *j* is 16, but does nothing to the other two terms.
I have also tried using the `Replace[]` function, but that doesn't work at all.

Of course, eventually I would like to write a '2D' for loop or similar to transform the rest of the expressions in the list. However, at this stage I am trying to get the substitutions to work on the first one to begin with.

Comment: It probably doesn't simplify because *Mathematica* considers the original expression to be simpler. One person's "simple" is another person's "horribly complex", because of course it depends on what you want to do with it. I suggest using replacement rules instead.

Comment: One possibility is to do something like `Vector /. Exp[time/Subscript[t, a_] - time/Subscript[t, b_]] :> cp[a, b]`. This doesn't exactly make the replacements that you wanted, but maybe you can work from there.